# Unable to Load Entities in Jboss Fuse ESB

Tags: jpa, jbossfuse

My META-INF/Persistence xml is as follows

```
  <persistence-unit name="jpapoc" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">

    <class>com.xxx.jpa.PersonEntity</class>
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <properties>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect" />
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create" />
     </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
```

My META-INF/spring/beans.xml as follows

```
  <cxf:cxfEndpoint address="/services/sm" id="sm"
    serviceClass="com.xxx.jpa.MyWebService">
    <cxf:properties>
        <entry key="dataFormat" value="POJO" />
        <entry key="setDefaultBus" value="true" />
    </cxf:properties>
  </cxf:cxfEndpoint>

 <bean id="myProcessor" class="com.xxx.jpa.PersonProcessor">
     <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
 </bean>
 <bean id="entityManagerFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="jpapoc" />
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
            <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect" />
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>

<bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource"
    destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClass" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" />
    <property name="jdbcUrl" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1523:xx" />
    <property name="user" value="test" />
    <property name="password" value="test" />
</bean>

<camel:camelContext>
    <camel:route>
        <camel:from uri="cxf:bean:sm?synchronous=true" />
        <camel:process ref="myProcessor" />
    </camel:route>
</camel:camelContext>
```

When i try to deploy this application in Jboss Fuse ESB I am getting **Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.xxx.jpa.PersonEntity not found by org.hibernate.entitymanager**

I have used @Entity in Person Entity classes and also gave dymanic import in pom.xml but still it is not working

Answer (score -1):

Its hard to point out the issue without having code.However you can check your bundled jar file if it contains the `com.xxx.jpa.PersonEntity` class.Also try adding `Meta-Persistence=META-INF/persistence.xml` instruction to your `pom` file.